# why i don't able to get value of a element of html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

here is the html content

```
<div id="result-box" class="col-5">
                <h3 class="result" id="name" >Name: --- </h3>
                <h3 class="result" id="age">Age: ---</h3>
                <h3 class="result" id="class">Class: --- </h3>
                <h3 class="result" id="skill">Skill:--- </h3>
                <h3 class="result" id="gen">Gender: --- </h3>
                <h3 class="result" id="perform">Perfomance: --- </h3>
            </div>
```

here is the js code You tell me what is the error/mistake in this

```
let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
let age = document.getElementById('age').value;
let class = document.getElementById('class').value;
let skil = document.getElementById('skill').value;
let gen = document.getElementById('gen').value;
let perform = document.getElementById('perform').value;

let name = document.getElementById('name').value
console.log(name)
```

In console panel it says undefined what is reason behind this, please guide me

Comment: `value` is used for input elements. You need to get the content via `textContent`

Comment: Or if using jQuery, [`$('#name').text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

```
let name = document.getElementById("name").innerText;
let age = document.getElementById("age").innerText;

let skill = document.getElementById("skill").innerText;
let gen = document.getElementById("gen").innerText;
console.log(name, age, skill, gen);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a few mistakes that could cause your behavior:

- You shouldn't define 'name' twice. If you want to overwrite the variable, then you mustn't repeat the 'let'.
- You can't use 'class' as a variable, it's reserved